# Disabling Firefox Security Warning

Tags: firefox, security-warning

Does anyone know how to disable Firefox's security warning:

```
Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.

Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?
```

I have set all `security.warn` to false in `about:config`. I still get the annoying pop-up.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If anyone from Firefox developers read this. I removed Firefox only because of that annoying warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of 12.x it still can't be disabled.

You can read a years-long argument [here on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436200) about this very issue. Log in and upvote it!

I have found complaints about this message going back at least six years. This is regularly reported on bugzilla and through the other Mozilla support sites and is a popular question on many other support forums. The main Moz devs apparently feel it is a critical security feature that should not be disabled. Personally I find it very annoying, I hit MSDN via Google searches all day long and I have to click through that stupid warning every time. If you see it a lot, it quickly becomes one of those warnings you automatically ignore which makes the "mandatory security feature" argument rather unconvincing.

Comment: Thanks @McGuireV10. To be honest, given degradation in Firefox performance due to its overhead or whatever and this annoying message, I have made Google Chrome my everyday browser of choice. I simply use FF to final QA test of my web sites. Too bad Firefox...

Comment: I can sympathize, FF performance has become worrisome, but I just can't cope with Chrome's anti-UI design... not yet, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

At least as of Firefox 16.x (and possibly before), the following strategy will disable the security warning:

In `about:config`, change the value of `security.warn_viewing_mixed` from `true` to `false`.

Also, the dialog box referenced in the question has a checkbox that says "Alert me whenever I'm about to view an encrypted page that contains some unencrypted information." You can simply uncheck that box the next time you encounter it, which will accomplish the same thing as manually changing the setting in `about:config`.

Comment: Doesn't work now any more.

Comment: It seems that in Firefox 115 the setting is called `security.warn_submit_secure_to_insecure`

Answer (score -1):

For me the below code handles the security pop up

IAlert alert = driver.switchto().alert();

alert.acccept();

Thanks

Anil

Comment: Is your solution javascript? How do you launch it @Anil

Comment: i am using c#,webdriver,MSTest.